# ListView items not getting populated when activity is launched

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Here is my scenario:
I have a `MainActivity` and a `CustomListViewActivity`. In my MainActivity, I have 1 button and 1 spinner. On click of the button, I pass the selected spinner value to the CustomListViewActivity via `Bundle` and using `Intents`.

Now, in my CustomListViewActivity, I have a ListView that uses `ArrayAdapter` for populating it. I send a `ArrayList` from MainActivity, say for example

```
 items = [abc]
```

In my CustomListViewActivity, I receive the same and use it to populate my ListView. The first time I do this, my value gets populated. The second time I do the same, the value existing is now replaced with the new one and the ListView shows one item instead of showing two.

So basically the problem is that the ListView is not updating and not showing both the items. Instead it shows me a single item always.

Here are snippets of my code

```
  MainActivity.java
```

//code inside button click
               ..

```
        {          
            items.add(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());


                 Bundle bundle =new Bundle();                   
                 bundle.putStringArrayList("data",items);


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyListViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
        }

        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
      Log.i("App","onSave");
      icicle.putStringArrayList("data",items);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle icicle2) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onRestoreInstanceState(icicle2);
           Log.i("App","onRestore");
       icicle2.putStringArrayList("data",items);
     }
```

MyListViewActivity.java

```
      private ArrayList<String> myItems;
      private static String[] titles;
      CustomListViewAdapter adapter;

  @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

          listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
          rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
          adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);

          b=getIntent().getExtras();

          if(b!=null)
          {
              myItems=b.getStringArrayList("data");

             titles= new String[myItems.size()];
             titles = myItems.toArray(myItems);
          } 


          ...

            int i=0;
        while(i<titles.length) {
            item = new RowItem(titles[i]);
            //rowItems.add(item);
            Log.i("ROW", ""+rowItems.size());
            i++;
            adapter.add(item);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);    
           }


           adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();            
    }

 }
```

How to make the ListView maintain the current data as well reflect the added data?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** : Forgot to mention one more thing. In my `MyListViewActivity` class I have a button above the ListView that on clicked takes me to my `MainActivity` so that I can add a new `Item` again. So when I go back to MainActivity and try and add a new Item , it's the new Item that get displayed rather than showing both the previous and the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to persist and restore your `items` list in MainActivity's `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods.

You also probably don't need to close the MainActivity by calling finish() every time you start the ListView activity but that depends on your application.

Basically, the problem you are having is that `items` is being recreated with each new instance of MainActivity. Since you finish MainActivity, a new instance is used every time you access that activity (and I assume you thought that items would just keep getting items added to it).

Comment: ok so in that case I need to add those 2 methods in my MainActivity and  add bundle.putStringArrayList("data",items); inside each of them right? Also do u think the MyListViewActivity is ok? I mean any changes over there

Comment: what about the onResume method in MyListViewActivity?

Comment: The MyListViewActivity is fine. If you used the 'add' method on your adapter to add RowItems you wouldn't need any of the code you have in onResume. If you wish to keep the manual notify, I would move the notifyDataSetChanged() call to after your while(i<titles.length) loop and delete your onResume method.

Comment: I have edited my code and added a few changes as per your comments. However still I get only 1 item in the list :( Please check above code

Comment: You may have misundertstood me. In onRestoreInstanceState you want to get items out of the Bundle. Try items =   icicle2.getStringArrayList("data");

Comment: Yes I tried that too but still it doesn't work. Also read the EDIT to my question above. One thing I observed is that when I press the back button and go back to MainActivity and select a new Item, I am able to see both the items in my List..why is that so?

Comment: Isnt that what you want? You maintaining this "items" list with all the items the user selected?

Comment: Based on your edit, it sounds as if you should pass the item list to the MainActivity instance as an extra in your intent. Then in the MainActivity onCreate, you can call getIntent() and add the list you passed over into the 'items' list